# Resetting & reseeding DB using rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

Using the code below to reset & reseed the DB

```
task init: [:environment, 'db:migrate:reset', 'db:seed']
```

`db:seed` creates a few users & few objects. It also updates `role` for few users.

`db:seed` throws following error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'role' for User`.

There is a migration file which adds `role` column to `User` table.

Unable to resolve this. Tries to write separate task for `db:seed`. Tried following

```
task init: [:environment, 'db:migrate:reset', 'db:seed'] do
  Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
end
```

Same `error` as before. Why is `column` from migration file isn't loaded for `db:seed` or I am missing something here?

Error log:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `role' for #<User:0x00007fd5ecb239e0>
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activemodel-6.0.3.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:432:in `method_missing'
/Users/Desktop/rails_app/app/models/user.rb:17:in `update_role'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428:in `block in make_lambda'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:605:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:604:in `catch'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:604:in `block in default_terminator'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:201:in `block in halting'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `block in invoke_before'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `each'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `invoke_before'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:134:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:825:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activemodel-6.0.3.2/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:117:in `run_validations!'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activemodel-6.0.3.2/lib/active_model/validations.rb:337:in `valid?'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:68:in `valid?'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:84:in `perform_validations'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:53:in `save!'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `block in save!'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:375:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:280:in `block in transaction'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:280:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:278:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:280:in `transaction'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:366:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save!'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:48:in `save!'
/Users/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:55:in `create!'
/Users/Desktop/rails_app/app/services/init_data:6:in `process'
/Users/Desktop/rails_app/db/seeds.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is the error message __exactly__? It's not "undefined method 'role' for User:Class", is it?

Comment: It throws undefined method error when db:seed tries to insert/update value for role column.

Comment: it's not what I asked. I asked for the full error message.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated the question with error logs.

Comment: Hm, indeed. From what I can tell, `db:migrate:reset` _should_ apply all migrations... If you inspect the database, is the column there? If so, might be the case of stale cache in ActiveRecord

Comment: Try `User.reset_column_information` in your seed task. This should reload latest User schema from the DB.

Comment: Thank you @SergioTulentsev. `reset_column_information` worked. It loads all the columns. In the meantime, I tried with `db:reset`, which runs `db:schema:load` instead of `db:migrate` which is also faster.

Answer (score 1):

Using `db:reset` solved the issue. i.e.

```
task init: [:environment, 'db:reset']
```

[db:reset](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fbe2433be6e052a1acac63c7faf287c52ed3c5ba/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L237) executes `db:drop, db:setup`.
`db:setup` executes `db:schema:load` whereas `db:migrate:reset` executes `db:migrate`. And `db:schema:load` is faster than `db:migrate`.

Not sure why `db:migrate` causes the issue.

As [Sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125816/sergio-tulentsev) suggested `stale cache` could be the cause. And his suggestion in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63397970/resetting-reseeding-db-using-rake-task#comment112104568_63397970) `User.reset_column_information` loads all the columns.